# Bed Up Against Wooden Fence

Tags: landscaping, drainage, fence

I have several planting beds along my wooden fence.  A landscape architect told me to simply put a board along the fence side to prevent the fence from rotting.
I did this but now the board settling and is too low..  Do I now need to pull it out and lay class 5 below it?

Comment: Was that board pressure treated?  I've done this with pressure treated 2X8's 2X12's.  I still would not allow that board to be buried by soil.  It sounds as if this would make a 'raised' bed using your fence and that is just not so.  What do you mean, class 5?   You are one great critical thinker to be questioning this dude's advice.  Or dudette...whatever.  Send a picture as if you were but a foot high off the ground to show the side of the berm, installed board, bottom of fence and the slope after the fence.  Please.  Did you hire this guy/gal?

Comment: Landscape Architects are subject to litigation after giving advice and that advice not working in most states. Grins, they should know better.  Let's see what you've done first and know a bit more.  He should have at the very least followed up.  We are like doctors and lawyers with as much education or more and sworn to be responsible. Also needing insurance and bonding.

Comment: That board should have been connected to the posts of your fence using screws, not nails.  I would have fitted an asphalt lining between the fence and this board to allow water to drain/evaporate.  The soil should never have covered that board more than 2".  At the bottom of that board.  Pressure treated board, 2X10 2X12".  Soil mounds upwards for the plant beds.  Please send pictures.  He might have been correct but didn't explain well enough.

Comment: Good grief, Stormy!  You're my hero.    
Thank you for the sadly vacant yet pertinent information.   
The concept of the board being affixed to the fence was not communicated.  Possibly should have been common sense..Ce'st la Vie.
No wonder it's sinking...  
Now to segway off topic...
In said bed, is a single trunk birch placed for privacy.  Will this Birch really reach 15 - 25ft in width and if so...how soon?  Am wondering if I should place another.    
I'm on an Urban lot, Minnesota, Zone 4b - 5 (sometimes:)
Will include pics in a bit..  Hold tight and thanks again!

Comment: Segway all you want!  You might want to make a separate question for the birch tree.  Is it Jacquemontii Birch?  If so, yes.  And soon like 5 to 7 years.  Gorgeous tree.  The other birch species are more tall than wide.  Jacquemontii is my favorite urban landscape birch.  Gorgeous bark and form and it can get as wide as tall.  Great privacy during the growing season, not so much in winter.  Send a picture or a few!  (What does 'sadly vacant' mean)? grins?